# Changing X intervals step python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I have Open_Time_H as a series of values

> plt.hist(Open_Time_H, bins=24, range=[0,24])
>
> plt.xlim(0,23)

[image: Result]

I would like to have a step of 1 for x axis, instead of 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
plt.xticks(range(25))
```